# How to upload images in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a tutorial/how-to for uploading and storing images in rails.
I searched google, but all I found was "...use imagemagick" or stuff like that.
But I did not find any step by step tutorial (including installing imagemagick or a different image-plugin).

Can you give me a step by step tutorial (including installing the required plugins)?
I am using Netbeans.

All I want is uploading images, resize images (save a picture in 3 different sizes), store images and display them.

Please help me! I need a tutorial for dummies :)

Comment: Do you want to store the image in a database or filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Railscast for using paperclip. Maybe this is for you...?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Comment: +1 was just writing the same. One alternative, if you prefer reading over watching a video: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Answer (score 1):

You use paperclip plugin. It is one of the most used plugin in rails.

Before that you have to install imageMagick.

Model look like this

```
class ImageClass < ActiveRecord::Base
# Paperclip
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100#",
    :large =>   "400x400>" }
end
```

you can set different sizes of images